# Elasticsearch Sorting "breaks" filter

Tags: django, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to split logs per customer. I think I understand the Query DSL of Elasticsearch.

For filtering the logs I use a domain name as filter parameter.
For this time we will call them

- bh250.example.com
- bh500.example.com

now I have managed to filter the logs so that the owner of domain bh250.example.com can only see his logfiles.

But when I want to sort them, based on the timestamp it "breaks" the filter and shows both bh250 and bh500 logs.

```
q =Q("match", domainname=domein)
q1 =Q("match", status="404")

search= Search(using=dev_client, index="access-logs").query(q).filter.("term" , status="200").sort("-@timestamp")[0:100]
```

Now without the Sort function it shows the correct logs, but in a different order. with the sort function i get both records on screen. (bh250 and bh500)

I also have looked at if mappings could be the issue but im not quite sure about why the sort function breaks down my "filter"

Comment: How does the mapping for the `domainname` field look like? What happens if you use a `term` query instead of a `match` query?

Comment: mapping the index using keyword analyzer fixed the issue

Comment: Cool, I was going to suggest that `domainname` was analyzed and it shouldn't be. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: for now this it the solution to the problem, but if i want to include subdomains i might get stuck

Comment: Feel free to ask another question when the time comes.